# SQLALCHEMY: Problem with subquery select, How do i a exact subquery with outerjoin?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'd like to get a select by a sub-query but, I don't know how I will do that. I searched for every world of internet but not found what i want.

The select is:

```sql
SELECT order_status.*
FROM `order`
LEFT OUTER JOIN
( 
    SELECT * 
    FROM (
        SELECT * 
        FROM order_status 
        ORDER BY created_date DESC LIMIT 1) s
    WHERE status IN ('NEW', 'FINISH','SENDED','PROCESSING')  
) AS order_status ON order.id = order_status.order_id;
```

my code:

```sql
subqy = self.session.query(OrderStatus).order_by(OrderStatus.created_date.desc()).limit(1).subquery()
query = self.session.query(Order).outerjoin(subqy)
return query.filter(and_(in_(conditions))).all()
```

Comment: Why do you need to join to the `order` table if you are not using anything from it at all? It is important to have it? If not, both the SQL query and sqlalchemy implementation can be much simplier.

Answer (score 0):

I'd change the query a little bit to remove one subquery:

```
SELECT order_status.*
FROM `order`
LEFT OUTER JOIN
( 
    SELECT * 
    FROM order_status 
    ORDER BY created_date DESC
    LIMIT 1
) AS order_status ON order.id = order_status.order_id
  AND order_status.status IN ('NEW', 'FINISH','SENDED','PROCESSING')
```

Then the code becomes

```py
subquery = self.session\
    .query(OrderStatus)\
    .order_by(OrderStatus.created_date.desc())\
    .limit(1)\
    .subquery()

query = self.session.query(Order)\
    .outerjoin(subquery,
               (subquery.c.order_id == Order.id)
               & subquery_a.c.status.in_(('NEW', 'FINISH','SENDED','PROCESSING')))
return query.all()
```

I think the thing you missed is that for subqueries, you need to access the columns through `table.c.column`, instead of `Table.column`, as you're used to.